# Call function in controller with $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When i run this i get no value at all, just endless looping errors. (***Error: [$rootScope:infdig]***)

My html:

```
{{getName(5)}}
```

This is my function:

```
$scope.getName = function(id) {
    $http.get('get.php?id='+id).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

When i call get.php?id=5 i get a normal answer like: "Jake Something"

When i call $scope.getName(5) in my controller i get the right value, no errors.

Is there a way to fix this or any other way to get the right values?

Comment: `getName()` returns a promise, and will get called every time angular runs a digest cycle.  You probably want to call it once when your controller is created and have it set a property on your scope that you put in your binding...

Comment: @Jason. That is why it was looping. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using directive:

```
myApp.directive('getCustomer', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope: {
            customerid: '='
        },
        template: "{{data}}",
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var url = 'get.php?id='+scope.customerid;
            $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                scope.data = response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

in html:

```
<get-customer customerid="5"></get-customer>
```

Outputs:

```
Jake Something
```